Horror film with friends trying to communicate with the dead girl with ouija board
So it was in 2015 there was a promo of a horror movie in the movie dracuşa (2015) and the that movie was based on group of friends trying to figure out who/what murdered their friend. They were trying to communicate with the dead girl with ouija board and I remember there was scene where the dead girl sewing one persons mouth and stuff. Possession and so on. I couldn't find that movie can someone help?

It was probably Ouija or Ouija: Origin of Evil.

Sounds like you're looking for the movie Ouija (2014)
The plot is centered around a group of friends using an Ouija board talking to a spirit, which they believe is their dead friend:

 Laine discovers the Ouija board that Debbie was playing with. Since she cannot shake the feeling that Debbie's presence is still in the house, she gathers Sarah, Trevor, Pete, and Isabelle to Debbie's house to play with the board. They get together and say the mantra as they put their hands together on the planchette. It starts to move, which everyone thinks is Sarah moving it. The spirit implies that it is Debbie and it spells out "Hi Friend" on the board.

The spirit itself has its mouth sewn shut and reproduces this on its victims:

 In her home, Isabelle is flossing her teeth and drawing herself a bath. She then has stitches form on her mouth, and she is levitated in the air. The spirit drops her, leaving her to slam her head against the sink, killing her.

